# Undifined reference to `vtable in for Base2 class

Tags: c++, vtable, undefined-reference

I have the code below:

```
// IBase.h
#include <iostream>

class IBase{
    public:
           virtual string getId();
};

// IBase.cpp
#include "IBase.h"
string IBase::getId(){};

// Base.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "IBase.h"

using namespace std; 
class Base : public IBase{
    protected:
           string id;
    public:
           Base(string _id);
           string getId();
};

// Base.cpp
#include "Base.h"

Base::Base(string _id){
    id = _id;  
}
string Base::getId(){
    return id;
}

// Base2.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Base.h" 
using namespace std;

class Base2 : public Base{
    public:
          Base2(string _id);
          string getId(); 
}; 

// Base2.cpp
#include "Base2.h"
Base2::Base2(string _id) : Base(_id){};
```

And i got the Undefined reference to `vtable in for Base2 when i compile the project! Is this i miss something?

Comment: By the way, putting `{};` in those cases is a warning under `-pedantic`. It might be worth putting in header guards too.

Comment: In response to chirs's comment, the correct way to specify an "abstract" function with no implementation is with the syntax `virtual void blah(int i) = 0;`. For example, your IBase class should look like http://ideone.com/VCO1D. No IBase.cpp needed.

Comment: if i remove the `IBase.cpp`, i got a compile error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined reference to vtable usually indicates that the first virtual function(where the vtable is usually stored) was not linked.

As no definition for `Base2::getId` is provided(the first virtual function), no vtable gets linked.

Either add a definition for `Base2::getId` or remove the declaration for the function in the class definition.

Comment: Thanks, so if in the `IBase` class, i have a `virtual` function, every inheritance class (son,grandson,...) must define the `IBase`'s `virtual` function, right?

Comment: @Kingfisher No, simply leave no declaration and it automatically inherits the one from the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

A function declaration needs a definition. Otherwise, a declaration would simply suppress the function definition (that was possibly inherited from a base). You have the following options:

- Remove the `string getId();` from `Base2` class declaration, or
- Define the function yourself, or
- Import a particular definition from a suitable base class via the an usingdeclaration such as `using Base::getId;`

Also note that the following:

```
 string IBase::getId(){};
```

- Needs to define a return statement (and return an object convertible to `string`)
- No semi-colon is required after the definition